# How to make my own package install external packages by default

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a question about installing external packages within my own package. Let's say my package requires two packages : ggplot2 and TTR. I create a new .R file which was saved in package R folder with code following :

```
#' mypackage
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name mypackage
#' @import ggplot2
#' @import TTR
NULL
```

Now `@import` command by default does not install lacking packages. During my package installation I get information that there is no package TTR. This problem does not occur when I manually install TTR package. Then `@import` command works properly and recognize TTR package. My question is : how can I tell `@import` command to also install lacking packages ? I tried load_all but it's not working.

Comment: “During my package installation” — *How* are you installing the package? Usually during package installation external dependencies *are* installed as well, though this isn’t necessarily the case when using a local installation. Either way this has nothing to do with roxygen2 and is purely due to how you install your own package.

Comment: If those packages are listed in the `Imports` or `Depends` field in your package description, they should be installed by default when the user installs your package, unless the user overrides the default by putting `dependencies = FALSE` in their `install.packages()` command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are probably encountering is that your package needs to be on CRAN so that `install.packages` also installs the external packages according to the value of the `dependencies` argument.

The reason for this is that `install.packages` assumes that the dependencies are located at the same place as your package.

If your package is a local `.tar.gz` or `.zip` file, you can use :

```
devtools::install_local('mypackage.tar.gz')
```

This will automatically get the CRAN dependencies defined in `@import`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add external packages to your package, have have to do the following:

- add package in DESCRIPTION file
- @import in .R file for roxygen2

In the description file you have to add a line:

```
Imports:
    stats,
    grDevices,
    ggplot2
```

In your .R file, when using roxygen2 you have to add a line:

```
#' @import ggplot2
```

roxygen2 then automatically adds ggplot2 to the NAMESPACE file for you (where it needs to be).

When somebody installs your package, ggplot2 will now be automatically be installed.

Just speculation, but maybe the problem was, that you or the user did not actually install the package, but instead has opened the .Rproj file and tried to build the package. Then I think you have to have the installed the package before manually.

Try to build your package. You get a tar.gz / .tgz and install the package in R Studio under Tools -> Install packages or with the install.packages command.